# Find integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $37469\alpha+52464\beta=-11$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $37469\alpha+52464\beta=-11$

(hint: First find $a$ and $b$ such that $37469a+52464b=\gcd(37469,52464).$

I want to make sure I did the steps correctly ; but i'm getting stuck here since the gcd $1,$ but the real question is asking us to equal to $-11.$

Okay following the comments, I got $a= -31195$ and $b= 22279$ when equaling to $\gcd 1$, now multiplying $a$ and $b$ by $(-11)$ I get that $a=343145$ and b=$-245069$ which does end up getting $-11.$ So my true $\alpha = 343145$ and $\beta= -245069$?

Comment: You can use gcd, equate the equation to gcd and multiply by -11 both sides.

Comment: How did you get $80825$ and $-57724$?  Was it hard or easy?  Did you have a method or did you stumble onto it.  Then hint is if $37469a = 52464 b = 1$ then $\alpha = -11a$ and $\beta = -11b$ will be solution. But if you don't *want* the hint you don't have to use it.

Comment: The $80825$ and $-57724$ was when I did the table and equaled them to $(-11)$, but following your instructions, I equaled the table to 1 which is the gcd, and that is how I got the large numbers.

Comment: Don't know what "doing the table" means.  Doesn't matter.  Thing is solving for $aK + bJ = m$ might be hit or miss but $ak + bj = \gcd(a,b)$ is very specific.  And we can get $aK + bJ = m$ but $(K,J) = (k,j)*\frac m{\gcd(a,b)}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "but i'm getting stuck here since the gcd 1, but the real question is
>   asking us to equal to -11"

Not a problem.

If $Ka + Jb = 1$ then let $\alpha = -11a; \beta = -11b$ and then $K\alpha + J\beta = -11$.

Of course those might not be the closest and "nicest" answers.

We can also let $\alpha = -11a + mJ$ and $\beta = -11b - mK$ where $m$ is any integer then $K\alpha + J\beta = -11Ka + mJK - 11Jb - mJK = -11(Ka + Jb) = -11$.

This way we can get numbers close together.

===

Example:

$52464 - 37469 = 14995$

$37469 - 2*14995=7479$

$14995 - 2*7479=37$

$7479 -  202*37 =5$

$37 - 7*5 = 2$

$5 - 2*2 = 1$

$(7479 -  202*37) - 2(37 - 7*5)=1$

$7479 - 204*37 + 14*5 = 1$

$7479 - 204*37 + 14*(7479 -  202*37) = 1$

$15*7479 - 3032*37 = 1$

$15*7479 - 3032*(14995 - 2*7479) = 1$

$6079*7479 - 3032*14995 = 1$

$6079*(37469 - 2*14995) - 3032*14995 = 1$

$6079*37469-15190*14995 = 1$

$6079*37469-15190*(52464 - 37469) = 1$

$21269*37469 - 15190*52464=1$

So $a = 21269$ and $b = -15190$ and

$\alpha = -11*37469 = -233959; \beta = -11*-15190=167090$ gives us

$-233959*37469 + 167090*52464 = -11$

However $-233959$ and $167090$ are very far apart (which is not a problem).

But if $\alpha = -233959 +6*52464 = 80825$ and $\beta = 167090 - 6*37469 = -57724$

we get your answer.

(Which aren't the absolute closest but ... who cares).

Comment: I updated the post to include the new corresponding a and b.

Comment: My $\alpha$ and $\beta $ are different but they still give me -11, which means that both answers are still correct right?

Comment: There infinite answers.  They are all of the form  $\alpha =28361 \pm k*52464$ and $\beta = -20255 \mp k*37469$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 3):

If you use (extended) Euclidean algorithm and find $a$ and $b$ such that $37469a+52464b=1$, you can multiply it by $-11$ to get $37469(-11a)+52464(-11b)=-11$. Thus, $\alpha = -11a$ and $\beta = -11b$ are the solutions you are looking for.

Comment: I got really big numbers, I updated my post can you see if my steps are correcting for getting the finals a and b?